# Use a jQuery variable in the same file as php echo

Tags: php, jquery, woocommerce

I have written the following code in `custom.php` file (just one file!):

```
jQuery(function ($) {
  $('.price_calc').hide();
   $('.lengthm2, .widthm2').keyup(function(){
     var priceProduct = <?php echo $priceProduct; ?>;
     var lengthM2 = $("#lengthM2").val();
     var widthM2 = $("#widthM2").val();
     var totalM2 = (lengthM2 / 100) * (widthM2 / 100);
     var totalPrice = totalM2 * priceProduct;
     $(".m2_customer_total").html(totalM2.toFixed(2));
     $(".price_customer_total").html('€'+ totalPrice.toFixed(2));
     console.log(lengthM2);
     console.log(widthM2);
});
```

Now in the same file I have added the following code:

```
<?php
        $lengthM2 = $_POST['length'];
        $widthM2 = $_POST['width'];
        echo do_shortcode( '[gravityform id="2" title="false" field_values="lengthM2='.$lengthM2.'&widthM2='.$widthM2.'"]' )
?>
```

I can't use the POST variables as I did not post anything.

But how can I manage this works correctly? I tried `$.post (jQuery)` which not works at all.